# 20000 images batch process photoshop

Tags: photo, photoshop

Hello i have around 100000 photos and 20000 need optimising.

I can run a batch process in photoshop however each image is across 100000 folders. They all have the same name. Is there a way to target the file name on a batch process in photoshop that you know of or should i be looking at alternatives.

Thanks

Comment: I think this should be moved to superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem with using the FOLDER > INCLUDE ALL SUBFOLDERS option?

[image]

Comment: its not subfolder but the names of certain images that needs to be targeted

Answer (score 1):

Write a script to create symlinks to your files into a single folder.
Then run the Photoshop batch on this folder. Your original files will also have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to select **override** Action "Open" and "Save As"

[image]